# Remote notification (GCM) into Xamarin.Android (monodroid) when app exit

Tags: c#, notifications, xamarin.android, push, xamarin

I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android)

The main problem is :

- What is `WAKELOCK_KEY` in their code ? What I must put here ?
- What is `classType` in their code ? What I must put here ?

For the `WAKELOCK_KEY` I just put "NOTIF", and for `classType` is use `typeof(MyIntentService)`.

I receive notification but can't receive notification when I kill the application. So how to manage this in Xamarin (no PushSharp or similar lib) ?

(My code is the same as in the tutorial, except for WAKELOCK_KEY and classType).

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the tutorial, you just have to do that (seems my solution for the wakelock_key and the classType was good) 
:-)

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MyIntentService.RunIntentInService(context, intent);
    }
}
```